# adjustbox with equation and tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, adjustbox

I want to write an equation on top of a tikzpicture within an adjustbox, but I'm getting this (I just wrote one equation):

[image]

the MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \def\firstcircle{(90:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
  \def\secondcircle{(210:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
  \def\thirdcircle{(330:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{outline}\1[$\blacktriangleright$]\emph{\textbf{aTitle}}:
\1[] \blindtext:

\begin{adjustbox}{width=5cm}
$ A \cup (B\cap C) = (A\cup B) \cap (A\cup C) $

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \secondcircle;
        \thirdcircle;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \thirdcircle;
    \end{scope}
        \draw \firstcircle node[text=black,above] {$A$};
        \draw \secondcircle node [text=black,below left] {$B$};
        \draw \thirdcircle node [text=black,below right] {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=5cm}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \secondcircle;
        \thirdcircle;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \thirdcircle;
    \end{scope}
        \draw \firstcircle node[text=black,above] {$A$};
        \draw \secondcircle node [text=black,below left] {$B$};
        \draw \thirdcircle node [text=black,below right] {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=5cm}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \secondcircle;
        \thirdcircle;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \thirdcircle;
    \end{scope}
        \draw \firstcircle node[text=black,above] {$A$};
        \draw \secondcircle node [text=black,below left] {$B$};
        \draw \thirdcircle node [text=black,below right] {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{outline}\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{width=5cm}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (90:3) {$ A \cup (B\cap C) = (A\cup B) \cap (A\cup C) $};
        \node[draw,circle,minimum size=3cm,inner sep=0pt] (c1) at (90:1) {};
        \node at (110:2) {$A$};
        \node[draw,circle,minimum size=3cm,inner sep=0pt] (c2) at (210:1) {};
        \node at (210:2) {$B$};
        \node[draw,circle,minimum size=3cm,inner sep=0pt] (c3) at (330:1) {};
        \node at (330:2) {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
```

Comment: Inspired by @AboAmmar to dig deeper in tikz

Comment: Also `\node[above] (current bounding box.north) {...};`

Comment: ah... I didn't see that syntax in the manual. thks

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372229/adding-a-text-node-to-tikz-drawing/372234#372234, maybe can help. And don't resize images and equations, better is scale `tikz` images or even better redraw it to desired size.

Comment: you mean using subfloats or minipages as in the example provided ? Why is that better than adjustbox ? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can place the equation below the first `A` circle, for example, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
  \def\firstcircle{(90:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
  \def\secondcircle{(210:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
  \def\thirdcircle{(330:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{outline}\1[$\blacktriangleright$]\emph{\textbf{a Title}}:
\1[] \blindtext:
%
\begin{center}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=5cm}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \secondcircle;
        \thirdcircle;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \thirdcircle;
    \end{scope}
        \draw \firstcircle node(A)[text=black,above] {$A$};
        \draw \secondcircle node [text=black,below left] {$B$};
        \draw \thirdcircle node [text=black,below right] {$C$};
   \node [below=of A] {$ A \cup (B\cap C) = (A\cup B) \cap (A\cup C) $};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=5cm}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \secondcircle;
        \thirdcircle;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \thirdcircle;
    \end{scope}
        \draw \firstcircle node[text=black,above] {$A$};
        \draw \secondcircle node [text=black,below left] {$B$};
        \draw \thirdcircle node [text=black,below right] {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=5cm}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \secondcircle;
        \thirdcircle;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \firstcircle;
        \thirdcircle;
    \end{scope}
        \draw \firstcircle node[text=black,above] {$A$};
        \draw \secondcircle node [text=black,below left] {$B$};
        \draw \thirdcircle node [text=black,below right] {$C$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{center}
\end{outline}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok. I hadn't thought of looking into doing it within tikz, and I didn't know it was so expressive. Cool. Thanks

Comment: For anyone looking, note: \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

Comment: And what about positioning it relative to the circle ? I'm finding it hard to do

Comment: Easiest is to specify the dimension in `below=<dimension> of A` also `above`, `left`, `right` or a combination of these, `below right`, `below left`, `above right`, etc...